# How do I bypass reCAPTCHA using Python Selenium Web Driver

Tags: python, selenium, recaptcha

I am working on a Python web scraping code to scrape a website, this is the link for the website https://publicrecordsaccess.fultoncountyga.gov/Portal/Home/Dashboard/29

I am using Selenium web driver to do so but I am trying to automate the code in a way that I do not need to manually click and bypass the reCAPTCHA. I looked at some codes online at GitHub to bypass it by solving the audio challenge using Python. But when I do so the reCAPTCHA will sense it and said I am using automated software. Then it will stop me from clicking the reCAPTCHA.

I am wondering are there any ways to bypass the reCAPTCHA using the Python Selenium web driver?

Thanks!

Comment: I mean, this is literally the point of a CAPTCHA. You will likely have a very difficult time finding a workable solution.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I think the same way too. I feel like they have been updating the CAPTCHA to prevent us to bypass it.

Comment: @CodingStark You "feel like" the updates are to prevent us from bypassing it and you're actually 100% right. That's the exact purpose of the updates, to make it more difficult for it to be bypassed. CAPTCHA stands for "Completely Automated Public Turing test to tell Computers and Humans Apart". You're doing the exact thing that CAPTCHA was designed to prevent.

Comment: @RandomDavis is that means there're basically no actual solutions for that?

Comment: @CodingStark any publicly available solution would be looked at by the CAPTCHA developers, meaning they could update it so that the solution won't work anymore. It's a constant arms race between the developers of CAPTCHA and the developers of bypasses. There's plenty of info online about this, even Python-specific info; I'm sure there are solutions out there that could work for you, or make it at least a little easier. If I were you I'd do a lot more research.

Comment: Yes, as Davis mentioned, of course they will update CAPTCHA to prevent abuse. This is roughly the same as saying "Help, armor manufactures produced new armor that a gun I'm building can't penetrate". The purpose of the armor is to protect. The makers *will* constantly improve their armor to prevent exactly what you're attempting to do here. There may be some existing solutions, but expect that they will be invalidated routinely.

Comment: There's paid services like capmonster cloud if you want it enough

Answer (score 0):

You can use [anti-captcha](https://anti-captcha.com)  is a paid service with a trial, you will need to create an account to have a API KEY

```
pip install python3-anticaptcha
```

an example use for RECAPTCHA V3

```
from python3_anticaptcha import ReCaptchaV3TaskProxyless
# Enter the key to the AntiCaptcha service from your account. Anticaptcha service key.
ANTICAPTCHA_KEY = ""
# G-ReCaptcha - website google key.
SITE_KEY = '6LeuMjIUAAAAAODtAglF13UiJys0y05EjZugej6b'
# Page url.
PAGE_URL = 'https://some_link'
# The filter by which the employee with the required minimum score is selected.
# possible options - 0.3, 0.5, 0.7
MIN_SCORE=0.3
# The value of the `action` parameter, which is passed by the recaptcha widget to google.
PAGE_ACTION='login'
# Get string for solve captcha, and other info.
user_answer = ReCaptchaV3TaskProxyless.ReCaptchaV3TaskProxyless(anticaptcha_key = ANTICAPTCHA_KEY)\
                .captcha_handler(websiteURL=PAGE_URL,
                                 websiteKey=SITE_KEY,
                                 minScore=MIN_SCORE,
                                 pageAction=PAGE_ACTION
                                )

print(user_answer)
```

[More info Here](https://pypi.org/project/python3-anticaptcha)

Also see [anti-captcha API documentation](https://anti-captcha.com/apidoc)